# how can I find the sequence number (index) of word in such a paragraph c++?

Tags: c++, indexing, cpu-word

I'm working on a project which needs to find the number of words and the indices of each word in the paragraph ...I have written the code which is counting the number of word in a string but I stuck with finding the indices of words,

such as : Hi John How are you I miss you ..

I need to print the indices like :  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

here is the code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int count_words(std::string);


    std::string input_text;
    std::cout<< "Enter a text: ";
    std::getline(std::cin,input_text);

    int number_of_words=1;
    int counter []={0};
    for(int i = 0; i < input_text.length();i++)
        if(input_text[i] == ' ')

            number_of_words++;

   std::cout << "Number of words: " << number_of_words << std::endl;
    //std:: cout << number_of_words << std::endl;
    system ("PAUSE");   

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question. If you count `n` words then your indices will be from `0 to n-1`. Or is it something different?

Comment: yes exactly, that's what I mean @bkVnet

Comment: So if you have the count, why don't you loop starting from `0 to n-1` display those number?

Comment: Off topic: `int count_words(std::string);` is a function prototype. It looks out of place here and doesn't seem to be used. Think on what you intend with this piece of code.

Comment: @bkVnet Can you write me an example please ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps. Edited to include use of count_words function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void count_words(std::string);

int main(){
    std::string input_text, output_text;
    std::cout<< "Enter a text: ";
    std::getline(std::cin,input_text);

    count_words(input_text);


    system ("PAUSE");

    return 0; //MUST RETURN AN INTEGER VALUE FROM 'INT MAIN'
}

void count_words(std::string inputString){
    std::string output_text;
    std::stringstream indexes;
    int number_of_words=0; //If there are no words, it would be false, make it 0.
    //int counter []={0}; //This serves no purpose.
    if(!inputString.empty()){// test to make sure it isn't empty.
        number_of_words++;
        for(int i = 0; i < inputString.length();i++){ // For loops should have curly braces {} containing their statement.
            if(inputString[i] == ' '){
                number_of_words++;
            }
            if((isalpha(inputString[i]))&&inputString[i-1]==' '){ //test for following space separated word
                indexes << i << " ";
            }

        }
    }

    output_text = indexes.str(); //convert stringstream to string

    std::cout << "Number of words: " << number_of_words << std::endl;
    //std:: cout << number_of_words << std::endl; //duplicate info
    std::cout << "Indexes: " << output_text << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @NonCreature0714 so many thanks..but I have an error in std::stringstream indexes; ..... that's (incomplete type is not allowed), 
do you have an idea??

Comment: ah, you have to #include<sstream>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand the question. You only need print the "indices"?? like this? (Using your own code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void stringTokenizer(const std::string& str, const std::string& delimiter, std::vector<std::string>& tokens) {
   size_t prev = 0, next = 0, len;

   while ((next = str.find(delimiter, prev)) != std::string::npos) {
     len = next - prev;
     if (len > 0) {
       tokens.push_back(str.substr(prev, len));
     }
      prev = next + delimiter.size();
   }

  if (prev < str.size()) {
   tokens.push_back(str.substr(prev));
  }
}

int main()
{

  std::vector <std::string> split;
  std::string input_text;
  std::cout<< "Enter a text: ";
  std::getline(std::cin,input_text);

  stringTokenizer(input_text, " ", split);
  int number_of_words = 0;
  for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = split.begin(); it != split.end(); it++, number_of_words++) {
    std::cout << *it << " " << number_of_words << std::endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks soo much, It's work fine ..I have another question please :
how can I  print each sentence with its index ??
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Think on this one: How many words in, `"          Hi John How are you       I       miss you "`?

Comment: I hope that Im helping to you learn and not only do your homework